# AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data, imblearn

I'm resampling my data (multiclass) by using SMOTE.

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state=1)
X_res, Y_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, Y_train)
```

However, I'm getting this attribute error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short answer**

You need to upgrade `scikit-learn` to version 0.23.1.

**Long answer**

The newest version 0.7.0 of `imbalanced-learn` seems to have an undocumented dependency on `scikit-learn` v0.23.1. It would give you `AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute '_validate_data'` if your `scikit-learn`is 0.22 or below.

If you are using `Anaconda`, installing `scikit-learn` version 0.23.1 might be tricky. `conda update scikit-learn` might not update `scikit-learn` version 0.23 or higher because the newest `scikit-learn` version Conda has at this point of time is 0.22.1. If you try to install it using `conda install scikit-learn=0.23.1` or `pip install scikit-learn==0.23.1`, you will get tons of compatibility checks and installation might not be quick. Therefore the easiest way to install `scikit-learn` version 0.23.1 in Anaconda is to create a new virtual environment with minimum packages so that there are less or no conflict issues. Then, in the new virtual environment install `scikit-learn` version 0.23.1 followed by version 0.7.0 of `imbalanced-learn`.

```
conda create -n test python=3.7.6
conda activate test
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.1
pip install imbalanced-learn==0.7.0
```

Finally,  you need to reinstall your IDE in the new virtual environment in order to use these packages.

However, once `scikit-learn` version 0.23.1 becomes available in Conda and there are no compatibility issues, you can install it in the base environment directly.

Answer (score 6):

***Step 1***- Open your jupyter notebook

***Step 2*** - type pip install --upgrade scikit-learn

***Step 3*** - Restart the kernel

Follow all the steps as it is and it's done!!(upgraded)

Comment: Yes rather than creating a new environment update scikit learn and restart the kernel

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO! For your next question like this, you'll probably want to include the versions of python, sklearn, and imblearn you are using.

I ran into this same problem myself and the developers have noticed it:
https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/727

Might want to follow this page to see if a solution is posted in the next few days. It seems to be about the sklearn library not being cleaned up properly after installing imblearn.

**UPDATE**
This can be fixed by updating your sklearn to Version 0.23 or higher. This should be possible for you through either:
`pip update scikit-learn`
OR
`conda update scikit-learn`

Comment: This is not solving the issue.

Comment: conda update scikit-learn does not work because the most recent version of sklearn is 0.22.1 on conda main

Answer (score 1):

although updating sklearn did not work for me as well, however setting up a new environment did , as proposed in one of the solutions provided in the link https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/727 mentioned in the answer.

Comment: please write the steps here for quick ref .. also it would get you some more upvotes ..

Answer (score 1):

### Up/Downgrading scikit-learn not working?

My OS: `Ubuntu MATE 18.04 x64`

Had this same issue and tried other solutions to no avail.

I was originally using `python 3.7.7` and got it working by using `python 3.6.8` instead.

**Anaconda**

```sh
conda create -n myenv python=3.6.8
conda activate myenv
pip install scikit-learn
pip install imblearn
```

**VirtualEnv** - *you will need python 3.6.8 already installed on your ystem*

```sh
virtualenv --python=python3.6 myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install scikit-learn
pip install imblearn
```

*verify versions*

```py
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
>>> '0.23.1'
import imblearn
imblearn.__version__
>>> '0.7.0'

...
# Now works
X_res, Y_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error recieved was**: AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

**Root Cause**: Requires scikit-learn 0.23, but in conda - python 3.7 we only have scikit-learn 0.22

**Solution**: Create Virtual Enviornment with python3.6.8 and install scikit-learn 0.23 as below

1. Create Virtual Env for python 3.6.8

   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> conda create -n myenv python=3.6.8
2. Activate the enviornment

   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> conda activate myenv
3. Install scikit-learn and imblearn in the virtual enviornment

   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> pip install scikit-learn
   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> pip install imblearn --user
   NOTE: this updates scikit-learn .... Collecting scikit-learn>=0.23
   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> conda list
   NOTE: it should be 0.23 ... scikit-learn              0.23.2                   pypi_0    pypi
4. Activate the kernel

   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv
   Installed kernelspec myenv in C:\Users\harish\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\myenv
   PS C:\Users\harish\Documents> cd C:\Users\harish\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\myenv

PS C:\Users\harish\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\myenv> ls

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        8/23/2020   6:41 PM            185 kernel.json
-a----        1/28/2020   2:18 AM           1084 logo-32x32.png
-a----        1/28/2020   2:18 AM           2180 logo-64x64.png
```

PS C:\Users\harish\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\myenv> cat kernel.json

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\harish\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "myenv",
 "language": "python"
}
```

5. In the Notebook you are working, Kernel>>Cange Kernel >> New Env

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading both sklearn and imblearn worked for me

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
!pip install --upgrade imblearn
```